# ANDROID java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, textview

**Buenas, tengo un error a la hora de abrir el fragmento de pelota, me da el siguiente error en el Logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

En la linea que me da el error es en el onCreateView():

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view;
```

Quisiera saber porque me da el error y como poder solucionarlo

Muchas gracias

Lo que deseo hacer es que una animacion**

```
    public class Pelota extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private int mPage;

    public static Pelota newInstance() {
        Pelota fragment = new Pelota();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelota, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        return view;
    }

    public void onClick (View view){

        ImageView imagen;
        imagen = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        Animation animacionPelota = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.botar);
        imagen.startAnimation(animacionPelota);

    }




}
```

Aqui dejo el codigo del XML que es RelativeLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Fragmento #4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="353dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/basketball" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: El problema es básicamente, que no le estas pasando la ubicacion: `TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tuTv)`

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente el elemento con id  `pelota` no es un `ImageView` por lo tanto no puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
ImageView imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pelota);
```

y obtienes el error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
> cast to android.widget.TextView

`pelota` en realidad es un layout ya que es la vista que inflas al inicio dentro de `onCreateView()`:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelota, container, false);
```

dentro de `pelota.xml` el id del `ImageView`  es `imagen`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="353dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/basketball" />
```

Debes obtener la referencia del ImageView y configurar su animaciòn de esta forma:

```
public class Pelota extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    private ImageView imagen;

    public static Pelota newInstance() {
        Pelota fragment = new Pelota();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelota, container, false);
        //Obtiene referencia de ImageView.
        imagen = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        return view;
    }

    public void onClick (View view){
        //Configura animación.      
        Animation animacionPelota = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.botar);
        imagen.startAnimation(animacionPelota);

    }



}
```